# Probability given by geometric model: $P(X=k) = p(1-p)^k$, calculate $P(X>1\ | \ X\le 2)$

Tags: probability, statistics

> Being $X\sim G(0.4)$, calculate:
>
> a) $P(X=3)$
>
> c) $P(X>1 \ | \ X\le 2)$

By $X\sim G(0.4)$, it means it follows the geometric distribution model with parameter $0.4$, that is:

$$P(X=k) = p(1-p)^k = (0.4)\cdot(0.6)^k$$

So in $a)$ we have $P(X=3) = 0.4\cdot 0.6^3 = 0.0864$

But what exactly means $P(X>1 \ | \ X\le 2)$? I know it's the probability of $X$ being greater than $1$ when $X$ is given to be $\le 2$, but how do I calculate it? It's certainly different from $P(1<X\le 2)$, which is the difference $P(X=2)-P(X=1)$

So what is the interpretation? I know that, given $P(X\le 2)$, we can only chose $P(X=0)$ or $P(X=1)$. He's asking the probability that given this situation, $P(X>1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\mathbb{P}(X>1|X\le 2)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X>1\space\cap\space X\le 2)}{\mathbb{P}(X\le 2)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=2)}{\mathbb{P}(X\le 2)}$

Comment: but why?? what's the interpretation?

Comment: This is the definition of conditional probability

Comment: It makes sense when you think about it. We clearly want that $\mathbb{P}(X=2)$ by the reasoning in the other answer, but we already have that $\mathbb{P}(X\le 2)$ so we're essentially restricting our sample space. The formula rearranged is $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A|B)\mathbb{P}(B)$ so you can think of it as the probabiity of $A$ and $B$ is the probability of $B$ and then the probability of $A$ given that we have $B$.

Comment: As for $A$ and $B$ we need $A$ and then $B$ given that we already have $A$. (Or $B$ and then $A$ given that we already have $B$). Hopefully this is slightly clearer but I agree it's not intuitive that this definition of "given that" is equivalent to the use in "real life" situation. Perhaps someone else can add to why this formula makes sense as I've probably made it less clear than it was before.

Answer (score 1):

$P(X\leq2)$ is equivalent to $P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)$. Since we need $P(X>1)$ given that $X\leq2$, we can only have $P(X=2)$. So you need to calculate $P(X=2)$.

Comment: It gives $0.144$ but my book says $0.1837$ :(

Comment: My fault, I forgot about the conditional probability properties.